# Mount Android Phone on Desktop

Tags: macos, file-transfer, android

Is there a way to mount my Android phone on my Mac Air desktop in order to transfer files like images and music?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/), created by Google itself, and it gives you a Finder window to at least transfer files via USB connection. I noticed, however, that you have to use the Samsung cable they provide to power the phone, and not some cheap knockoff USB cable.

It would be nice to have a way for the icon to mount on the desktop via a Bluetooth connection -- but that's just not possible yet.

There is also the [free Handshaker application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/handshaker-manage-your-android/id1012930195?mt=12) in the Apple Store that is more full-featured and intuitive than Google's Android File Transfer. So far, it's looking like my best option and I don't see quirks except that I had to [enable Android Developer Mode and then turn on USB Debugging on](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/), as well as uninstall Android File Exchange because it conflicts with it.

Comment: Android File Transfer doesn't actually give you a Finder window. It has its own window that looks like Finder, but isn't. Normal Finder interactions do not work: You can't, for example: Get Info; See folder size; ... and most other stuff you would expect to be able to with Finder.

Comment: With my Android 10, I can only see the SD card and not the internal phone memory (tested with Àndroid file Transfer` and `Handshaker`). I enabled developer's mode on the phone but cannot see the internal memory from that apps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use "Android debug bridge" (ADB) command line tool. It is intended to use it for testing and deploying apps under development, however it enables users/developers to run commands like `adb ls` to list all files and `adb pull sdcard/DCIM/Camera ~/Documents/` will copy all the files in the sdcard/DCIM camera folder to Documents. Read more on how to install and use the tool here. Note adb requires the phone to have enabled developer mode and USB debugging. Read more here; https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Answer (score -1):

Still, if there was another app to accomplish this, it would be much better as this official app hasn't been updated in over 5 years. Also, handshaker has recently broken. (At least for the time being)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. If you have a different question, ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can also add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to get more users interested in the question. You can also read [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve your chances on getting a good answer.

Comment: Handshaker is no longer in the Apple store. I had to download it from their Hong Kong website I think and the chars were in another language. I think I clicked EN or something to see it in English. I then downloaded and it worked just fine. I backed up my old Android and got a new Android. That was last month (April 2017).